# What is the best tool to grind down a smaller metal rod?

Tags: tools, metal, metal-cutting

I am building [this workbench](http://www.popularmechanics.com/home/how-to-plans/woodworking/4219723?click=main_sr) and I have decided to recess the nut and washer inside the top of the bench, so that I won't cut/scape myself while I'm leaning up against it.

Now my issue is that the rod is sticking out with sharp edges and needs to be ground down to stay inside the 1" recess I bore in.

My question is, what is the best tool (preferably a Dremel bit) to grind down this 3/8" metal rod.  The most I'd need to grind is about 1/2" of length.

I was at the hardware store and someone recommended a diamond coated bit used to grind stone, but it didn't do anything for the metal.

Attached is a picture of what I am doing.  Forgive the roughness, I still haven't sanded/beveled the edges.

[image]

Comment: Could you cut the rod to length **before** threading it through the bench top?  If so, a hacksaw and file would be all you'd need.

Comment: What you are looking at is the face of a 1x2, so as I tighten the nut on the rod, the width of the workbench changes by up to 2" so its possible to guestimate, but at this point im already at the point where I need them to just be cut

Comment: you could screw an acorn nut on the rod to cover the threads. Loosen the nut and tighten the other side so the exposed end will be away from you.

Comment: I like that idea!

Comment: You say you were having trouble estimating length: now that you know how long the screw needs to be, mark it with a pen and back it out. Then cut it to that length and re-assemble.

Comment: Backing it out is easier said than done.. Its a 4ft long 3/8" rod in a 3/8" hole drilled through about 50 1x2's.  Cutting is easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Dremel cutoff wheel to cut off a piece of the rod but you may have to remove the rod to do this.  You can use Dremel grinding wheels to grind down the end of the rod.  If the rod is not protruding out of the hole, you could use a wooden plug to seal off the hole.  Sand the plug flush with the bench top.

Comment: I actually plugged the holes with dowel and it looks rather nice